# How do I create a table in Microsoft Word such that the table edges are not double-struck?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have used Microsoft Word thousands of times before to format my tables.

However, now I can't get the table borders to be single-struck.

I always either have two lines, or zero lines, but never one line.

BORDERS AND SHADING DIALOGUE / MENU:

[image: borders shading menu]

SINGLE_STRUCK_WITH_NO_INNER_EDGES:

[image: single no inner edges]

DOUBLE_STRUCK_WITH_INNER_EDGES_AND_OUTER_EDGES:

[image: double inner outer edges]

Comment: Is this a problem if you start Word in safe mode? https://support.office.com/article/dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72 Can you save a sample document on OneDrive and post a view link in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Table Options via Table Properties.  I can replicate the issue by ticking "Allow spacing between cells" in Default cell spacing in that dialog.